# How to map and filter duplicate values in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How I get unique value of category_id column data 
here is my console log data

```
0: {category_id: "37", status: "4", category_name: "GO Thrones"}
1: {category_id: "41", status: "3", category_name: "need for speed"}
2: {category_id: "84", status: "4", category_name: "new"}
3: {category_id: "41", status: "3", category_name: "need for speed"}
4: {category_id: "37", status: "4", category_name: "GO Thrones"}
```

Comment: you want category_id to be any unique number

Comment: @MaheerAli yes sir

Comment: @Gnanaseelan what is the expected output

Answer (score 2):

Using **Object.keys()** we can return all the unique Id values with **.reduce()**.

```
const data = {
    0: {category_id: "37", status: "4", category_name: "GO Thrones"},
    1: {category_id: "41", status: "3", category_name: "need for speed"},
    2: {category_id: "84", status: "4", category_name: "new"},
    3: {category_id: "41", status: "3", category_name: "need for speed"},
    4: {category_id: "37", status: "4", category_name: "GO Thrones"}
}

const results = (data) => 
    Object.keys(data).reduce((result, key) => {
        (!~result.indexOf(data[key].category_id)) &&
            result.push(data[key].category_id);
        return result
    }, [])


console.log(results(data)); // ​​​​​[ '37', '41', '84' ]​​​​​
```

And here is the same refactored into a one liner for convenience, although obviously not as legible.

```
const results = (d) => Object.values(d).reduce((r, i) => !~r.indexOf(i.category_id) ? (r.push(i.category_id), r) : r , []);

console.log(results(data)); // ​​​​​[ '37', '41', '84' ]​​​​​
```

Comment: pendingProductList.map(category =>
          console.log("mydata=",category.category_id)
          );  now i got all category_id (37,41,84,41,37)

Comment: @Gnanaseelan I have updated to only show category id if it doesn't exist in array